# Pandas scan directory to fix multiple corrupted excel files;merge all or few fixed files into one dataframe

Tags: excel, pandas, merge

a struggling python newbie. I would like to do the following:
(1.) fix multiple corrupted excel files in folder by looping over them to fix them; save restored/fixed files to new location
(2) merge all (or selected) of the fixed/restored excel files one pandas dataframe. *If possible, I would like the code to be able to choose say first 10 files, due to low memory.*

The code stops running at the very first file and indicates no such file, while the file does exist in the directory. Assistance with both codes would be highly appreciated. Thanks.

Please find attached the notepad containing the code and the error message (issues pasting code here).

```
file_dir = r"""C:\Users\Documents\corrupted_files""" 
for filename in os.listdir(file_dir):
    print(filename)
    file= os.path.splitext(filename)[0]
    # Opening the file using 'utf-16' encoding
    file1 = io.open(filename, "r", encoding="utf-16")[0]
    data = file1.readlines()
    xldoc = Workbook()
    # Adding a sheet to the workbook object
    sheet = xldoc.add_sheet("Sheet1", cell_overwrite_ok=True)
    # Iterating and saving the data to sheet
    for i, row in enumerate(data):
    # Two things are done here
    # Removeing the '\n' which comes while reading the file using io.open
    # Getting the values after splitting using '\t'
        for j, val in enumerate(row.replace('\n', '').split('\t')):
            sheet.write(i, j, val)
    # Saving the file as an excel file
    xldoc.save(r"C:\\Users\\Documents\\restored_data\\" + file + ".xlsx", 51)   


    #need assistance with code to loop over fixed(restored) multiple excel files, combine, e.g.all or 
only first 10 into one dataframe

ERROR MESSAGE BELOW

*20181124_file_01.csv
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
FileNotFoundError                         Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-37-17a38b97f646> in <module>
4     file= os.path.splitext(filename)[0]
5     # Opening the file using 'utf-16' encoding
6     file1 = io.open(filename, "r", encoding="utf-16")[0]
7     data = file1.readlines()
8     xldoc = Workbook()
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '20181124_file01.csv'*
```

Comment: This is too complex a question for stackoverflow. By not splitting off the FileNotFoundError into its own question, it makes it look like you are just foisting off the whole work onto someone else.

Answer (score 0):

Code should be:

```py
for filename in os.listdir(file_dir):
    print(filename)
    file = os.path.join(file_dir, os.path.splitext(filename)[0])
    with open(os.path.join(file_dir, filename), "r", encoding="utf-16") as fh:

        xldoc = Workbook(fh) ## think you can use a file handle as a reference here.
        # Adding a sheet to the workbook object
        sheet = xldoc.add_sheet("Sheet1", cell_overwrite_ok=True)
```

`listdir` returns only the filename and not the entire file path.

It might also be worth putting a `with` statement around your call to `io.open` so that it destroys references after using.

You shouldn't get low memory - as reference to each workbook should be destroyed before you open the next.